# Should I expect problems when communicating via RMI between Java5 and Java6?

Tags: java, rmi

Basically the subject says it all: We have a couple of components running on Java 5, they're talking to each other via RMI. Should we expect any problems, if we move some of them to Java6? By moving I mean compiling them with `-source/target 1.6` and running on a java6 vm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you shouldn't expect any problems with that. But anyway take a look to [the Release notes for RMI in java 6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/relnotes.html)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

We have successfully pulled in Java 5 serialized objects into Java 6 objects so there should be no limitation  on the serialization front.

You should also be able to switch between 32bit and 64bit Java as well without issues.